# What is the default value of "output" attribute for cfproperty getter/setter?

Tags: properties, interface, coldfusion

I am implementing a `<cfinterface>` in a component. One of the purposes of this interface is to make sure that certain properties (cfproperty) are defined within the component. So, I have explicitly created function prototypes for getters/setters in interface and set `accessors="true"` in `<cfcomponent>` tag.

Now, I want to use `output="false"` for these functions in interface but it gives me an error:

> **Argument output value mismatch.**
>
> The <FunctionName> function does not specify the same value for the output argument in the <ComponentName> ColdFusion component and the <InterfaceName> ColdFusion interface.

How can I make sure that the default getter/setter has `output="false"`?

Comment: I don't think the output setting should be specified in the interface, should it? Interfaces are for specifying the API behaviour, not how generated output is handled. That said, you'll need to roll your own accessors if the autogenerated ones don't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  You'll have to write your own getters and setters if your interface happens to have `output="false"`.  I usually omit that for new interfaces, or omit using interfaces altogether.

The default value of `output` attribute is not to have the `output` attribute defined at all (wrapped with nothing).  It's not just `true` (wrapped with cfoutput) or `false` (wrapped with cfsilent).